# how to store and display the html elements using react js

Tags: reactjs

how to display html elements in react java script window through scripting. I have tried using json data but the elements are hard coded in html.

suggest me how to approach.

```
 class App extends Component {   
       constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        data: '',
      }
    }
  componentDidMount() {
   fetch('http')
       .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
            // fetch the text
      fetch(response.url)
              .then(response2 => response2.text())
              .then(response2 => {
                this.setState({
                  data: response2
                })
              })
          })
        }
 render() {
    return (
        <div>
         {this.state.data}
        </div> 
      )
    }
  }
  export default App;
```

Comment: please put what you have tried in question, otherwise you get down-voted

Comment: what do you mean by store? as I understand you mean how to render the HTML elements using react js. right? you can read that doc if you want that https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Unfortunately, it is not clear what you are asking in the question above, nor what you have tried thus far.  I would recommend reading [ask] and [mcve].  Welcome and happy coding!

Comment: I am not sure, is that you need ?  hope data is something like '<div class="ext">Hello!</div>' and you need to render it. Is this need ? you have to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML for this. check the demo once https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cymfnd